# PHP upload rename image and send as attachment in email

Tags: php

I'm busy with a PHP upload and mail function basically it takes uploaded images and puts it in an email as an attachment and then also uploads it to a directory, how would i rename the image according to the date but keep the extension, for people may upload images with the same file name...

here's the upload function:

```
$newdirectory = "applicants";
$count = 0;
foreach ($_FILES['myfile']['name'] as $filename)
{
    $temp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$count];
    move_uploaded_file($temp, $newdirectory . '/' . $filename);
    $count++;
}
```

and then the entire php function:

```
<?php
    function printMember($member) {
        foreach($member as $key=>$value) {
            //Fill the aux string first
            $str.= "$key : $value <br />";
        }
        //string that will be added to $msg variable inside the loop
        return $str;
    }

    $json = $_POST['parameters'];
    $json_string = stripslashes($json);
    $data = json_decode($json_string, true);
    $depCount = count($data["dependants"]);

    $msg .= "<h2>Main member data:</h2>";
    $msg .= printMember($data["mainmember"]);
    $msg .= "<h2>There are $depCount Dependants</h2>";

    foreach ($data["dependants"] as $index => $dependant) {
       $msg .= "<h2>Dependant $index</h2>";
       $msg .= printMember($dependant);
    }

    $strTo = "chante@jamfactory.co.za";
    $strSubject = "Image Testing";
    $strMessage = nl2br($msg);

    //*** Uniqid Session ***//
    $strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    $strHeader = "";
    $strHeader .= "From: Dawid<xxx@xxx.co.za>\nReply-To:xxxx@xxx.co.za";

    $strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";
    $strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

    $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
    $strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";

    //*** Attachment ***//
    $count = 0;
    foreach($_FILES['myfile']['name'] as $filename)
    {
        $temp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$count];
        $strFilesName = $filename;
        $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($temp))); 
        $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
        $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n"; 
        $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
        $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";
        $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";
        $count++;
    }


    $flgSend = @mail($strTo,$strSubject,null,$strHeader);  // @ = No Show Error //

    if($flgSend)
    {
        echo "Mail send completed.";
        $newdirectory = "applicants";
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($_FILES['myfile']['name'] as $filename)
        {
            $temp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$count];
            move_uploaded_file($temp, $newdirectory . '/' . $filename);
            $count++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Cannot send mail.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Look for the last '.' (strrchr), remember that substring and then append it to whatever you renamed the file to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `pathinfo` for excluding the file extension, plus adding an extra `timestamp` to prevent the file name conflicts and replacing the existing files.

```
$newdirectory = "applicants";
$count = 0;
foreach ($_FILES['myfile']['name'] as $filename)
{

    $temp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$count];
    $file_info = pathinfo($filename);

    // Don't you forget to have the $user available here ...
    $filename = $user . '_' . time() . '.' . $file_info['extension'];

    move_uploaded_file($temp, $newdirectory . '/' . $filename);
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: Your answer seems the best so far, but my php isn't that great, how would i use this with my code?

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven I've updated the answer, hope this works. Remember that you need the `username` to be ready there, otherwise just remove it from my code ...

Comment: hey i but the user name there ready for action and i also tried removing, i doubt its the problem, but im only getting one file uploaded instead of multiples and also the one file is named : test_1359985637.

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven yeap, there was a bug there, but I guess I've killed that by now, check the updated version of my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

with `move_uploaded_file()`..  you get to pick the filename..

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). **If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.**

so you can do

```
 $newfilename='yourFileName';
 move_uploaded_file($temp, $newdirectory . '/' . $newfilename);// this will save your filename with newfilename from temp to newdirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to get extension and rename the new file name :

```
foreach ($_FILES['myfile']['name'] as $filename)
{ 
     $temp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$count];

     $ImageExt = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.'));
     $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);

     $filename = "YOUR_NEW_NAME_HERE".$ImageExt;
     move_uploaded_file($temp, $newdirectory . '/' . $filename);
     count++;
}
```

If file name contains multiple dot(.) then you can use `substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);` and [pathinfo](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) will also help you.

Comment: What if the filename contains multiple dots?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: I am not sure, but substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1); this will solve your prob.